# Index Match for multiple column criteria in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to create a map for multiple columns in Python.

**Data**

```
id  date     type
aa  q1 2021  aa
bb  q1 2022  aa
cc  q1 2021  aa
cc  q1 2022  aa
cc  q1 2023  bb
```

**Desired**

```
id  date     type  source
aa  q1 2021  aa    10
bb  q1 2022  aa    20
cc  q1 2021  aa    10
cc  q1 2022  aa    20
cc  q1 2023  bb    50
```

**Logic**

when we come across the year 2021 and the type aa, the source value will be 10
when we come across the year 2022 and the type aa, the source value will be 20
when we come across the year 2023 and the type bb, the source value will be 50

**Doing**

```
map = pd.DataFrame([
    {'id': 'aa', 'date': '2021', 'source': 10},
    {'id': 'bb', 'date': '2022', 'source': 20}
])


df['source'] = df1.type.replace(map,regex=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `merge`:

```
mapper = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 'aa', 'date': '2021', 'source': 10},
                       {'id': 'aa', 'date': '2022', 'source': 20},
                       {'id': 'bb', 'date': '2023', 'source': 50},
                      ])

df["year"] = df["date"].str.split().str[1]
output = df.merge(mapper.rename(columns={"date": "year", "id": "type"}), how="left").drop("year", axis=1)

>>> output
   id     date type  source
0  aa  q1 2021   aa      10
1  bb  q1 2022   aa      20
2  cc  q1 2021   aa      10
3  cc  q1 2022   aa      20
4  cc  q1 2023   bb      50
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary that maps the tuple `(type, date)` to your desired value.

Based on your logic, such a dictionary could be:

```
map = {('aa','2021'): 10, ('aa','2022'):20, ('bb','2023'): 50}
```

Then you can apply this dictionary to the `'type'` and `'date'` columns of your DataFrame:

```
df['source'] = df[['type','date']].apply(lambda x: map[x[0], x[1]],axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   id  date type  source
0  aa  2021   aa      10
1  bb  2022   aa      20
2  cc  2021   aa      10
3  cc  2022   aa      20
4  cc  2023   bb      50
```